# How to find number of subtractions in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

Here's the code:

```
def f(k):
    if k<3:
        return 1
    return f(k-1)+f(k-2)+f(k-3)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question needs more information. What is the expected output for this function? Does it return the wrong output? For which input?

Comment: What do you mean by *"number of subtractions"*? The number of (recursive) calls to the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a decorator to count calls to the function:

```
def count(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.pop("reset", False):
            wrapper.calls = 0
        wrapper.calls += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.calls = 0
    return wrapper
    
@count
def f(k):
    if k<3:
        return 1
    return f(k-1)+f(k-2)+f(k-3)
```

Now you can count function calls:

```
>>> f(5, reset=True)
9
>>> f.calls
13
>>> f(23, reset=True)
532159
>>> f.calls
798251
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same output as @schwobaseggl by using global variable:

```py
count = 0
def f(k):
    global count
    count+=1
    if k<3:
        return 1
    
    return f(k-1)+f(k-2)+f(k-3)
print(f(23))
print(count)
```

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @quamrana. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: I searched and got this, explaining why we shouldn't use global variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Comment: Yes, in the case of your answer, there is no other function which could use `count` to count the number of calls. Other functions would need their own count. This is what the decorator in the other answer neatly encapsulates.